# Get a field from a table when using MAX function

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

I have the following MySQL statement which is working well.

```
SELECT c.id, IFNULL(MAX(l.id), 0) as level_id
FROM course c
LEFT JOIN level l ON c.level_id = l.id
WHERE c.user_id = '123'    
GROUP BY c.id
```

A course can have multiple levels so the `IFNULL(MAX(l.id), 0)` works by selecting the highest.

However, instead of returning the id of the highest level, I would like to get the name. I tried the following but MySQL doesn't like joining using a value in the select.

```
SELECT c.id, IFNULL(MAX(l.id), 0) as level_id, l2.name
FROM course c
LEFT JOIN level l ON c.level_id = l.id 
INNER JOIN level l2 ON level_id = l2.id
WHERE c.user_id = '123'     
GROUP BY c.id
```

I have simplified my statements in my questions (for readability), so hopefully the problem still makes sense.

Comment: The first query should give you an error as you have a WHERE clause in the middle of the JOINs (code looks the same as you 2nd query to me).

Comment: @Kickstart thanks for spotting, updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this type of query, I think the easiest method is the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
SELECT c.id, COALESCE(MAX(l.id), 0) as level_id,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(l2.name ORDER BY l.id DESC), ',', 1) as name
FROM course c LEFT JOIN
     level l
     ON c.level_id = l.id INNER JOIN
     level l2
     ON level_id = l2.id
WHERE c.user_id = '123'
GROUP BY c.id;
```

Note that the `WHERE` is misplaced in your query.

Caveats on this approach:

- You need a different separator if `name` might have commas.
- There is an internal limit on the length of the `group_concat()` intermediate result.  If this is an issue, the length can be increased.

Comment: I do wonder if the 2nd join on to to the level table is necessary (would be if there is a dummy level with an ID of 0). However think the join condition will struggle anyway as I think it is meaning to use the result of an aggregate function (ie, to cope with the l.id of 0)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to do a sub query and join the results of that back against the level table to get the level name:-

```
SELECT sub0.id, sub0.level_id, l2.name
FROM
(
    SELECT c.id, IFNULL(MAX(l.id), 0) as level_id
    FROM course c
    LEFT JOIN level l ON c.level_id = l.id 
    WHERE c.user_id = '123'
    GROUP BY c.id
)
LEFT OUTER JOIN level l2 ON l2.id = sub0.level_id
```